# symfony 3.0.9 routing как правильно записать роут в формату yml

Tags: symfony, маршрутизация, config

Всем привет не могу сообразить как записать короче!
Мне нужно чтоб все что приходит на субдомены отправлялось в один котнролер 
сейчас заместо субдомена использую отдельный хост который указываю в parametrs.yml

```
navigator_api_homepage3:
    path: /{route}/{route2}/{route3}
    host: %navigator_host%
    defaults: { _controller: NavigatorApiBundle:Default:index }
    options:
       requirements:
          route: ^.+
          route2: ^.+
          route3: ^.+

navigator_api_homepage2:
    path: /{route}/{route2}
    host: %navigator_host%
    defaults: { _controller: NavigatorApiBundle:Default:index }
    options:
       requirements:
          route: ^.+
          route2: ^.+

navigator_api_homepage1:
    path: /{route}
    host: %navigator_host%
    defaults: { _controller: NavigatorApiBundle:Default:index }
    options:
       requirements:
          route: .+

navigator_api_homepage_main:
    path: /
    host: %navigator_host%
    defaults: { _controller: NavigatorApiBundle:Default:index }
```

Answer (score -1):

Скорее всего Вам нужно добавить префиксы, создать в бандле какой-нибуть routing.yml :

```
# config/parametrs.yml

app_file:
    # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
    resource: '@NavigatorApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
    prefix:   /home
```

а в `routing.yml` уже строить конкретные маршруты

```
navigator_api_homepage3:
    path: /home/{route}/{route2}/{route3}
    controller: NavigatorApiBundle:Default:index
    defaults: { route2: NULL, route3: NULL}
    options:
       requirements:
          route: ^.+
          route2: ^.+
          route3: ^.+
```

Использовать только 1 кконтроллер и тем более 1 action для разных логических абстракций очень плохая идея, вам прийдется делать кучу проверок вместо того, чтобы разбить на контроллера или акшена.